# python: In memory file object, is there a point reading them with chunks

Tags: python, django

If we have a large file, there is a technique reading and processing it with chunks.

Lets say I have received a file inside a request (as i see it's InMemoryFile object), and want to read it contents. Is there any harm if I will read it all at once using read(), or it's better to read it with chunks?

UPDATE:

The thing which is not clear to me yet is: if we get a request (with inmemory object) doesn't it mean that the file is already in memory? I can't see any other place it can be stored. If it's already in memory, what .read() is changing?

Comment: I suppose it would depend on how large the file is, and how much memory you have.

Comment: Regarding your update, that was my thought. "Reading" from such a file will just copy the chunk you read into a new string, so the thing to balance is how much of the data you copy per read vs how many calls to `read` you'll make.

Comment: Did you mean it is a `InMemoryUploadedFile` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Django always provides you with a file-*like* object when uploading a file. If the file isn't too large, it'll provide you with an in-memory object, if it *is* too large, it'll be streamed to disk first.

See [Where uploaded data is stored](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored):

> By default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory. This means that saving the file involves only a read from memory and a write to disk and thus is very fast.

By always giving you a file-like object, you don't have to adjust your code to special-case the in-memory variant, but you won't have to suffer the performance hit a larger file has to suffer by reading from disk.

For an in-memory file object, the [`.chunks()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.chunks) will just return the whole file contents. For larger files, you'll get a series of chunks that are small enough to allow for efficient processing.

If you are not doing anything else with the strings, reading from an in-memory file object won't actually create new strings; as the string is immutable it can safely be shared instead.